# Android newline in my EditText

Tags: android, json, utf-8, android-edittext

i got some data like this  "line 1 \n line 2" from my distant server by using json with utf8 encoding, and when i try to put the data in my EditText the newline \n doesn't work in spite of unscaping the data by using URLDecoder.decode() because i use databases.
Any suggestions

all the best .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved , by using

```
myString.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String value=userdataArrayList2[0].toString().trim().replace("\\n", "\n");
```

In back end database insert data like this :

```
name is osama\nibrahim
```

*result:*

```
name is osama
ibrahim
```